# How do I remove Admin from my shipping label?

Tags: magento2, shipping, usps

My company has set up the USPS shipping module and we have started printing shipping labels through Magento 2.

Our only problem is that each time we print a shipping label, the name on the label says Admin. I have searched all over the backend, gone through every tab and can't find where this data is coming from.

Could somebody help me figure out how to remove this from our shipping labels?
*(Bonus points if you know how to disable signature confirmation because it seems to be automatically applying to each USPS order)*
[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you take the screenshot where you want to remove? I cannot see.

Comment: In the picture above, I am trying to remove the part that says "ADMIN ACCOUNT". Or at least be able to change that to say something else.

Comment: You said that `My company has set up the USPS shipping module`, seem that you're using a custom module? You can give me the link of this extension?

Comment: Ah yes, we are using the XAdapter USPS Shipping Plugin for Magento 2.0 w/ Stamps.com . We just recently made the switch to this extension but we had the same problem before we made the switch. We thought this would actually solve it but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer just in case anyone ever gets stuck with this issue.
The Admin Account name was actually coming from my Magento Admin Panel account name. I wish I would have not given it such a generic name or else I may have solved this issue sooner.

Anyway, the solution is as simple as logging into the backend Admin panel, going to
System -> All Users -> Add New User
 Whatever name you input into first and last name for that user will be displayed on the postage when printing it out using USPS or any extension for USPS.